# Type inference failure with Convert.ToInt64

Tags: c#

The following snippet

```
static class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     dynamic data = "0001010";
     var value = System.Convert.ToInt64(data);
     System.Console.Out.WriteLine(value.DoubleIt());
  }

  static long DoubleIt(this long source)
  {
      return source * 2;
  }
}
```

fails with

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'long' does not contain a definition for 'DoubleIt'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at Program.Main()
```

while a small change of

```
long value = System.Convert.ToInt64(data);
```

or of

```
string data = "0001010";
```

is sufficient to make this work.

Looking at the IL, it appears that the former is trying to load DoubleIt via reflection, while the latter cases result in DoubleIt being statically bound.

Any suggestions why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `value` is actually `dynamic`. At compile time, we don't *actually* know which `System.Convert.ToInt64` method is being called - it could be any of the overloads (if there are any).

Therefore, you need to explicitly say `value` is `long`. This tells the compiler you know what you're doing, and if you don't you'll get a runtime error (If for example, `ToInt64` returned a `string`). Or, you can remove the dynamic invocation (which you did by replacing `dynamic` with `string`) - at which point we know *exactly* which `ToInt64` method is being called.

When you write `DoubleIt()` - you are not actually binding to the extension method. `dynamic` doesn't care what you write, and will try to resolve it at runtime as a method on the object itself - and does not take extension methods into account

Extension methods are simply syntactic sugar, and compile down to this in IL:

`SomeStaticClass.DoubleIt(value)`
Which makes it more clear as to *why* it fails to run `value.DoubleIt()`

Comment: And trust me, it is impossible to invoke an extension method on a dynamic object in C# 4. I tried, really really hard.